CSV data value being imported to SQL Server with incorrect $ value
I've got a CSV report exported from our accounting system that I've imported into a SQL Server DB. I used the SQL Task- Import Flat File to do so. When I compared the imported dollar values, there were several entries that were a few pennies off from the original export.
I allowed the utility to create the table and the fields affected were created as Float datatype.
Here are some examples:
Per Book,2024,Nov,Company Name,101-100-000,236174.43
was imported as
Per Book,2024,Nov,Company Name,101-100-000,236174.44
Per Book,2024,Nov,Company Name,120-000-000,4257212.30
was imported as
Per Book,2024,Nov,Company Name,120-000-000,4257212.50
Per Book,2024,Nov,Company Name,128-300-000,-725158.82
was imported as
Per Book,2024,Nov,Company Name,128-300-000,-725158.81
Per Book,2024,Nov,Company Name,128-400-000,2327315.42
was imported as
Per Book,2024,Nov,Company Name,128-400-000,2327315.50
Can anyone explain this and offer a solution?

Float is your problem. Its not an accurate datatype... you need money or decimal. You'll need to specify it manually rather than letting it automatically choose.

exactly... use decimal for money, this is a common problem

Thanks Dale K. and Flash. Is it possible to get Import Flat File utility to create the field correctly?

@RickSavoy just hit advanced when prompted to map columns and set the field type manually

Not sure that's the only issue, 0.42 to 0.5 is quite a large increment, shouldn't happen for float, although it could be something with scifi notation

There's no advanced button, but I overlooked the fact that the Modify Columns screen allows one to change the datatypes. Changing the datatypes to Money corrected the issue. -Still, the changes when using float are quite puzzling.

You might want to read up on the float datatype... its important to understand when dealing with databases.

I suspect that the data was treated as a real at some point, @siggemannen , which is only accurate to 7 digits. The numbers suffering large inaccuracies are larger numbers.

I think there's something else going on here other than float. Yes float and real are approximate numeric types and so shouldn't be used when accuracy is required, but they cause different problems with the example numbers than what's reported in the question. float, real

Conversion to REAL (32-bit IEEE-754 floating point) exactly matches the observed behavior.  For values from 131072 to 262144, the accuracy is 1/64. For values from 4194304 to 8388608, the accuracy is 1/2. For values from 524288 to 1048576, the accuracy is 1/16. For values from 2097152 to 4194304, the accuracy is 1/4. (See this db<>fiddle, which calculates the epsilon value for several ranges of values.)

See also this db<>fiddle that demonstrates the result of SELECT Value, CAST(CAST(value as Real) AS Decimal(19,2)) AS Rounded FROM ( VALUES (236174.43), (4257212.30), (-725158.82), (2327315.42) ) V(Value). Results: 236174.44, 4257212.50, -725158.81, 2327315.50.

"Changing the datatypes to Money corrected the issue." I suggest against money as well, @RickSavoy , it's just a "disguised" int. Use a decimal as suggested before. Something like a decimal(16,4) would likely be appropriate.

@TN that's a very nice script, almost deserves an answer :)
